# SQLServerExeption trying to insert NULL value in a column

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm having trouble to insert a NULL value in a float-type column that allows null values. I'm getting this exception:

```
SQLServerException: Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with float
    at (...)
```

I'm using `PreparedStatement` to query the database. The piece of code I use to set this specific value is:

```
Float floatValue;

(...)

if((this.floatValue != null)&&(this.floatValue != 0)) ps.setFloat(col_pos,this.floatValue);
else ps.setNull(col_pos,java.sql.Types.NULL);

(...) int result = ps.executeUpdate(); //Here is when i get the error, when it tries to insert/update the table).
```

What am I doing wrong? This piece of code works (in other parts of my code) for `nvarchar` or `int` columns, it's the first time I get this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your `Float` column accept a null?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm totally sure. If I query manually the statement (using Management Studio), it allows me to insert a NULL value.

Comment: what is the datatype of the column in database?

Comment: the datatype for the affected column is `float`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **gbn**'s answer, I realized what is really happening when I use `ps.setNull(col_name, java.sql.Types.NULL)` in my code. I was wrong, I needed to specify the  type of the column I was inserting the NULL-value to. So the solution was:

```
ps.setNull(col_name, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);
```

When I needed to set a null-value in a column I first used `ps.setInt(col_name,null)`, but it returns an exception as the setter methods use standard basic types (int,float,...) rather than objects. I searched for a solution and I (wrongly) learned that I needed to use `ps.setNull(col_name, java.sql.Types.NULL)`. The

Why `java.sql.Types.NULL`? I didn't know, I thought it was the way to add a null in a column.

Then gbn's said:

> varbinary will cast implicitly to nvarchar and int but not float
>    (...) 
>   *I suspect you are **not** storing a true database null in the nvarchar and int columns*

So I considered that possibility that, internally, my connection was creating a *varbinary NULL* and the exception appeared when trying to convert it to a Float type, not supported according to the graph referred by gbn. Then I tried to specify a `java.sql.Types.FLOAT` type and it worked.

I hope this explanation would help other users with similar issues. Thank you **gbn** for providing me the hints.

Answer (score 4):

`varbinary` will cast implicitly to `nvarchar` and `int` but not `float`.

See the graph here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx

I suspect you are **not** storing a true database null in the `nvarchar` and `int` columns

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you... so you are saying that, when I use `ps.setNull` the code is internally creating a `varbinary` and, when it tries to put it on a `float` column fails?

So, how can I insert a `NULL` value in a `float` column? Is there any way?

Comment: @jmrodrigg: yes, there a varbinary somewhere. However, I don't know how to fix it sorry. I don't use Java